# merge three arrays with same length & get an array of equal length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have three arrays:

```
arr1= [1,2,3,4,5];
arr2= [a,b,c,d,e];
arr3= [p,q,r,s,t];
```

I want to merge these & get another array as shown below:

```
arr4= [1:a:p, 2:b:q, 3:c:r, 4:d:s, 5:e:t]
```

Please suggest how can I do it using java script?

Comment: What have you tried and what's the problem? See [ask] and [mcve] for details on how to ask a question.

Comment: The expected result isn't valid JS. Are those supposed to be strings?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the exact result you are looking for is not possible in JavaScript, you would be getting a string array since you want to have both strings and numbers present within the same element:

```
var result = ["1:a:p", "2:b:q", "3:c:r", "4:d:s", "5:e:t"];
```

That said, here's a couple solutions.

You can loop through them and add a concatenation to a result array:

```
var arr1= [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr2= [a,b,c,d,e];
var arr3= [p,q,r,s,t];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    result.push(arr1[i] + ':' + arr2[i] + ':' + arr3[i])
}

console.log(result);
```

Or use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var arr1= [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr2= [a,b,c,d,e];
var arr3= [p,q,r,s,t];

var result = arr1.map(function(val, i) {
    return arr1[i] + ':' + arr2[i] + ':' + arr3[i];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this will create an array of string

Comment: @brk In JavaScript, what he wants has to be an array of strings, as he has both numbers and strings in the initial arrays. The exact result he wants is not achievable.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the first array with `map` function and get the index of the items into the passed function. Use the `index` to access other arrays items and make your desired result. This works if you have the same length for all arrays.

```js
const arr1= [1,2,3,4,5];
const arr2= ['a','b','c','d','e'];
const arr3= ['p','q','r','s','t'];

const mappedArray = arr1.map((item, index) => `${item}:${arr2[index]}:${arr3[index]}`);

console.log(mappedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take all arrays or an arbitrary count of arrays in an array and map the values at the same index.

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    arr3 = ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't'],
    result = [arr1, arr2, arr3].reduce((a, b) => a.map((c, i) => c + ':' + b[i]));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want. If so, please search a little bit before asking questions implying simple functions.

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
var arr2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
var arr3 = ['p','q','r','s','t']
var arr4 = []
arr1.forEach(function (elm, idx) {
  arr4.push(elm + ':' + arr2[idx] + ':' + arr3[idx])
})

console.log(arr4) // ['1:a:p', '2:b:q', '3:c:r', '4:d:s', '5:e:t']
```